# draw2d on drag start event

Tags: javascript, draw2d, draw2d-js

I want to call my custom callback function every time, when user starts dragging figures. I tried to do it like so:

```
figure.onDragStart = function (x, y, shiftKey, ctrlKey) {
    myfunc();
};
```

But the problem is, every time when my function is called, figure is positioned to 0,0 coordinate. I'm not sure what is wrong with that and how can I fix it.

Comment: can you provide myfunc code?

Comment: yes, sure. it may be just `function myfunc(){ console.log("Hello world") }`. So, it is just an arbitrary function.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return true;` to `figure.onDragStart`?

Comment: I've just tried `figure.onDragStart = function () { return true; }` and got the very same effect. So, it seems like the library itself positions the figure to `0,0` point when this event is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redefining the `onDragStart` method, you can handle the `dragstart` event:

```
figure.on("dragstart", function(event, ui) {
    // Do something
});
```

According to [the draw2d documentation](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_6/#!/api/draw2d.Figure), that event is triggered by `onDragStart`. The `ui` parameter contains `x`, `y`, `shiftKey` and `ctrlKey`.

You can see the code in action in [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/zk8ng16h/). A message is displayed in the console when you start dragging a rectangle. The green rectangle uses the `dragstart` event and responds correctly. The red one redefines the `onDragStart` method, with the problem mentioned in your question.